# Display an image gathered from the app depending on device resolution

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable, screen-resolution, android-youtube-api

In my app, I am getting different resolutions of images from URL and I put them in a Bitmap to finally send it to the screen. 
The problem is that I don't find a way to choose between the different resolution automatically depending on the screen resolution of the device. Since I get the images while the app is running, I can't put them in the drawable folders before...

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be smarter to only retrieve the images from the server for the device resolution in the first place?

Comment: And my bad.. you will want to pick the right image based on the dpi not for the resolution of course ;)